# ORM Mapper .NET linux server

Tags: .net, mysql, linux, oracle, orm

I have already tried a lot of ORM mappers and there seems to be always some parts that are missing or some things that I really don't want to use.

The following parts are a must have for me to use a ORM mapper:

- It has to be possible to use the mapper on a linux server. It would be ok for me to use a two tier approach if the ORM is able to help me a bit out there. That means for example that it should be possible to use ref cursors (Lightspeed for example seems to be not able to use more than one ref cursor per function) from stored procedures (at the moment the application runs on a Oracle DB, but I would also like to be able to support MySQL and SQL Server in the future ... so I would prefer not to use this approach) or maybe some kind of statement batching (to avoid having unnecessary round trips to the db). 
  The other possibility that would be ok is if the mapper is able to run his server part on mono without any issues (mainly performance).
- Validation: I need to be able to validate the user input before I send it to the server. That means automatic functionality to include at least string length checks (these should be shown in a WPF UI).
- Easy to use
- Should work with an existing Oracle database (I have no problems with using some third party provider like dotConnect).
- Possibility to migrate from Oracle to another db without to much manual work. I would like to support MySQL and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NHibernate](http://nhforge.org) seems to be a good candidate. Personnaly, I use [DbLinq](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007) but it doesn't include validation (i.e. you must do your own validation in entity classes).

Comment: Yes it looks like if there is no way around NHibernate. It seems to be just the most flexible solution.